# Compare element inside a struct with a void pointer value in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, compare, void

I need to create a funcion that receive a struct pointer and a void pointer, it return 1 if the element is on the struct.

```
typedef struct {
    char *sx;
    int val, code, qtty;
    char abc [20];
} ST_DAT;

int compare (ST_DAT *, void *);
```

This is part of a program that compare nodes in a double linked list, but this funcion is used as:

```
int (*pfun)(ST_DAT *, void *));
```

The problem is that I don't know how to compare the `void *` to the other values until I find or not the value inside.

```
int compare (ST_DAT *stData, void *key)
{
    if (key == (*stData).val || key == (*stData).code || key == (*stData).qtty || strcmp (key,(*stData).abc) || strcmp (key,(*stData).sx) )
    {
       return 1;
    }else{
       return 0;
    }
 }
```

Is this correct?

Comment: How is `compare` supposed to be called?

Comment: ... or even more specific: What is being passed as 2nd parameter when is `compare()` called?

Comment: ...press this f... f... funny shift next time if you type in an "I"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(*stData).val` is of `int` type, therefore you need to cast `key` to `int *` and then dereference it like this:

```
*(int *)key == (*stData).val
```

Comment: If i want to use the -> operator it would be like:   *(int *)key == stData->val right?

Comment: Depending on what is being passed as `key` such code will be facing ugly alignment issues. You shall not cast a `char`-pointer to become an `int`-pointer if i the pointer never was pointing to an `int` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to typecast the `key` as per the data you are comparing. And you got to make sure that you are comparing the value at the pointer and not the pointer itself in case of `int`.

```
  if (*(int*)key) == (*stData).val || *(int *)key == (*stData).code || (int *)*key == (*stData).qtty || strcmp((char *)key,(*stData).abc) || strcmp ((char *)key,(*stData).sx) )
```

Comment: there you go. Sorry was offline after pasting the source.

Comment: Your approach faces the same issues as I commented on in my comment to haccks' answer..